# Using Android Samples/Examples in app

Tags: android, google-play

If I use Android Samples/Examples in app and altered it around. Could I put in into the play store? For example if I take the snake game, put different sprites and features, could I call it my app?

Are the Google samples they include with their SDK, copyrighted and not reusable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every sample there's something like below. You may want your lawyer to have a look at that so he can advise

> /*  * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project  *  *
>   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");  * you
>   may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  * You
>   may obtain a copy of the License at  *  *
>   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0  *  * Unless required by
>   applicable law or agreed to in writing, software  * distributed under
>   the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,  * WITHOUT WARRANTIES
>   OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.  * See the
>   License for the specific language governing permissions and  *
>   limitations under the License.  */

Comment: @SarimA. I, personally, have no idea what it means. Lawyers they do.